# Websocket lost connection issue

Tags: django, web-applications, websocket

I am implementing a project with django channels and have faced with an unexpected issue. Due to specific of this web app, I need the established websocket connection, on every page of this app, but unfortunately when I click to navbar menu, the page reloaded completely, and websocket lost it connection. 
So, could you professionals give me a clue of how can I make one websocket connection, which will never be lost, no matter how many times the webpage be reloaded?
P.S.
I couldn't make navbar static and separate from the page, cause it's slightly different on each page for some design and usability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use javascript to the maxmimum to make your DOM without loading a new page.
Or you should seperate the websocket connection from web app and connect it with os-native functions.